# SSRS - Generate more than one tablix for from one dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I would like to know how can I generate more tablixes from one dataset. Let's say, based on how many values of certain column I get from the data set.

Example:

```
System | Status | KPI | Description
--------------------------------
A      | Active | 90% | bla
B      | InActive| 85% | bla bla
C      | Active | 99% | bla ba
```

system column should be the one that determines more tablixes to be generated. Then in this case, there will be 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a List to your report, group by the List by System.

And insert your tablix in the List.

You should get one tablix for each System.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can create other tablix with the same dataset and apply filter to this tablix for show other data.